# pandas dataframe replace does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace double quotes `"` in a dataframe column. Column value us something like this

```
" This is some text
Another text     "
```

I tried

```
dataframe['columns_name'] = dataframe['column_name'].str.replace('"','')
dataframe['columns_name'] = dataframe['column_name'].str.replace('\"','')
```

I also tried using regex, but it doesn't work as well.
I am using Python 2.7

EDIT

This is how I am reading the values.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(file_name,sep=',',names=[list_of_columns],dtype={columnnames:object})
dataframe[column] = dataframe[column].str.replace('"','')
```

dataframe.to_csv(new_file_name,sep='|')

Now I open new_file to check values

Comment: Why is it not working. Its working for me. Try passing the regex as a character class i.e `.str.replace('[\"]','')`

Comment: That is what I do not understand as why it is not working. I have tried using regex and passing it as character class the way you mentioned. Still, no luck

Comment: How are you checking the column? Are the assigning and replacing column name same?

Comment: Check Edit. I have added some details.